# redirect native stderr (not the log file) of gradle daemon to a file

Tags: gradle, gradle-daemon

For a few weeks my builds (even the smallest projects) randomly fail with:

```
Could not dispatch a message to the daemon.
```

Gradle daemon writes its logs to `~/.gradle/daemon/$version/`, however, in daemon.out.log the last message is:

```
Executing build with daemon context
```

I added to my global `gradle.properties` the line:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n
```

and unfortunately, the message: `Listening for transport dt_socket at address` is missing in the log. Still, I was able to attach a debugger and I see that `System.err==org.gradle.internal.io.LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream@3bf76e6d`. Maybe this trick works while the VM is still alive, but what happens when it crashes? It seems that a JVM crash output won't be written to that file.

So my question is: how to configure Gradle to redirect the daemon's native stderr to a file so I can troubleshoot further?